# How to define xsi:type as an attribute in XML-schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML for which I want to write a schema definition. The problem is that I don't know how to define xsi:type as an attribute. Here is the XML element:

```
<SerializedData xsi:type="xs:double">300.0</SerializedData>
```

My XML-schema definition so far looks like this:

```
<complexType name="SerializedDataType">
    <simpleContent>
        <extension base="double">

        </extension>
    </simpleContent>
</complexType>
```

I have also tried defining it like Ian Roberts suggested:

```
<element name="SerializedData"/>
```

However, when I use BPEL designer to initialize it like this:

```
<SerializedData xsi:type="xs:double">300.0</SerializedData>
```

I get the following warning:

> The fixed value you entered does not appear to be valid XML (which is required for some types of fixed values to work correctly). It will be saved in a text format.

If I initialize it like this there is no warning:

```
<SerializedData>300.0</SerializedData>
```

But the problem is that the Web Service I am trying to invoke expects the request SOAP message to include the attribute xsi:type="xs:double". How can I make my SOAP request message to include it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to - just declare the element without a type at all.

```
<element name="SerializedData" />
```

The `xsi:type` attribute is used to indicate to the schema validator that the real type of a particular instance of an element is not the element's declared type but rather a sub-type derived from the declared type. By declaring the element with no type you are saying it can have *any* type, and you will use `xsi:type` in the instance to specify which.

Strictly you're declaring an element whose type is the "ur-type" which is the root of the XML Schema type hierarchy - all types, simple and complex, ultimately derive from the ur-type. If you want to restrict the `SerializedData` element to simple content only (no sub-elements or attributes) then declare it as

```
<element name="SerializedData" type="anySimpleType" />
```

Regarding the second part of your question, your designer tool is right that in isolation

```
<SerializedData xsi:type="xs:double">300.0</SerializedData>
```

is not correct XML, because the `xsi` namespace has not been declared. Try adding the namespace declarations:

```
<SerializedData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:type="xs:double">300.0</SerializedData>
```

Comment: Thank you Ian Roberts for your reply. Please read my edited question.

Comment: "If you want to restrict the SerializedData element to simple content only (no sub-elements or attributes) then declare it as" what if I want it to restrict to type that extends particular complex type instead?

Answer (score 7):

The xsi:type attribute doesn't need to be declared in the schema: it's implicitly declared, and can be used on any element. But in an instance, it has to be a valid QName.

If you write

```
<SerializedData xsi:type="xs:double">300.0</SerializedData>
```

then

(a) to be namespace-well-formed, you need to declare the "xsi" namespace

(b) to be schema-valid, you also need to declare the "xs" namespace.

As Roberts indicated, this means you should write

```
<SerializedData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:type="xs:double">300.0</SerializedData>
```

Comment: Must the "xsi:type" value be prefixed with "xs:"?

Comment: The xsi:type can be any type defined in the schema, it doesn't need to be a built-in type.

Comment: Would xsi:type="double" be valid? Would it know which schema double belonged to?

Comment: xsi:type="double" would be valid only if you have a no-namespace schema that defines a type with local name "double". It wouldn't match the type "double" in the XML Schema namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The answers in this thread were not really comprehensible for me, I have found another thread that has a more explicit explenation of the solution: [C# serializing xsi:type and xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379512/c-sharp-serializing-xsitype-and-xsd).