# XSD namespace issue

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to modify my XSD to suit the corresponding XML file (`Test_1.xml`). The point here is that in XML I am encountering an attribute (**name of attribute is "type") with `xsi` namespace**... But I don't know *how to specify the namespace separately for an attribute in schema defination*?

Code extract:

```
<ns:return xsi:type="ax261:StatisticsReturnWS"
           xmlns:ax259="http://ws.transverse.ese.esepa.soprabanking.com/xsd"
           xmlns:ax263="http://error.transverse.ese.esepa.soprabanking.com/xsd"
           xmlns:ax262="http://retour.socle.ws.ese.esepa.soprabanking.com/xsd"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:ax261="http://retour.ws.ese.esepa.soprabanking.com/xsd">
  <ax262:returnCode>0</ax262:returnCode>
  <ax261:statisticMessageWS **xsi:type="ax261:StatisticMessageWS"**>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define xsi:type as an attribute in XML-schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216778/how-to-define-xsitype-as-an-attribute-in-xml-schema)

Answer (score 1):

The xsi:type attribute does not need to be explicitly declared in your schema: it is declared implicitly and is allowed for every element.

If it were some other namespaced attribute, e.g. xlink:href or xml:id, then you would need to create (or obtain) a schema document for the relevant namespace (xlink or xml), ensure that it contains a global attribute declaration for this attribute, import that schema document into your "main" schema document, bind a prefix to the relevant namespace URI, and then reference the attribute in your complex type definition, e.g. as

```
<xs:attribute ref="xlink:href"/>
```